# Find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{5n^3+2n^2}{3n^3+2n})z^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, limsup-and-liminf

> Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{5n^3+2n^2}{3n^3+2n})z^n$

I know Hadamards lemma says that $\frac{1}{R}=\lim\sup \vert a_n\vert^{1/n}$

But I'm not sure how to compute $\lim\sup \vert a_n\vert^{1/n}$

I can see the $(a_n)\to 5/3$, so I believe $\lim\sup \vert a_n\vert$ should just be the limit of the sequence? But I'm not sure how to actually use the lemma to find $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cauchy-Hadamard theorem is often a power hammer to kill a fly.

You can just notice that the series diverges for $z=1$ as its term doesn’t converge to zero in that case. And that the modulus of its term is less than $\frac{5}{2}\vert z\vert^k$. As the series $\sum z^k$ converges for $\vert z \vert \le 1$, the radius is equal to $1$.

Comment: Ok thanks. What do you mean by the modulus of its term being less than $5/2 \vert z^k\vert$?.

Comment: I mean $\left\vert \frac{5n^3+2n^2}{3n^3+2n}z^n\right\vert \le \frac{5}{2}\vert z\vert^n$ at least for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Rational functions don't matter
when finding the
radius of convergence
since
$\lim_{n \to \infty} (n^k)^{1/n}
=1
$
for any real $k$.

(This follows from
$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}
=1
$.)

Also note that
$a^{1/n} \to 1$
for any $a > 0$.

So, in this case,
the radius is 1 -
this converges for $|z| < 1$.

Also,
since
$a_n \to 5/3,
a_n^{1/n} \to 1
$.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance I could tell that converges when $|z|<1$ ,maybe it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Since $a_n \to 5/3$, there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that

$$1 \le a_n \le 2$$

for $n>N.$ Hence

$$1 \le a_n^{1/n} \le 2^{1/n}$$

for $n>N.$  This gives

$$ a_n^{1/n} \to 1.$$